# Getting an error: "has no exported member"

Tags: asp.net, angularjs, angular, asp.net-core

So [this is my test app](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/34699414/2ndCoreAngularTest.zip) I'm tried building. Please download to see code.

I was following instructions from the [TypeScript site here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/asp-net-core.html).

I'm getting these 2 errors in the pic. [image]

1 - Can anyone tell what's wrong?

2 - Does anyone have a link to a recent tutorial that shows how to setup an ASP.NET Core project with Angular 2 that actually works?

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Don't ask for external resources, its not suitable for StackOverflow questions. Read the FAQ: http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic *Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.*, only concrete/specific programming related questions/problems

Answer (score 2):

app.ts should be like this

```
export class MyApp { //export class here
    model = new MyModel();
    getCompiler() {
        return this.model.compiler;
    }
}
```

so that you can import at the time of bootstrap your app

Comment: Thanks. That knocked out one error. I still have the tsc.exe exited with code 1. Know how to fix that?

Comment: Will you please explain bit more about current error ?

Comment: It doesn't say much except what's in the screen shot I mentioned earlier. Prob easier if you download the project file to see the error. The link is in the orig post. I think it's related to typescript compilation.